# In Oracle APEX 5.1, is it possible to adjust the width of an interactive grid?

Tags: oracle-apex

The application builder consistently sizes interactive grids about 10 characters wider than the screen.  So the final column is always cut off, even if there is only a few columns.  I've found I can set the minimum width of a column, so I've been setting the last column very wide so that the value in the column will be visible, but there must be a better way?  How is Apex determining the width of the interactive grid?

Comment: This is a bug which will be fixed in 5.2.  The best thing to do is set the minimum width to a small number so that they all display on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the page:

- click the "Actions" button
- choose "Columns"
- set "Minimum column width (pixel)" for each column